# flexDirection: 'row' squishes components

Tags: react-native

I have a `TextView` in a `View`. It looks like this:

```
+----------+
|TextInput |
+----------+
|          |
|          |
+----------+
```

but as soon as I put `flexDirection: 'row'` into the style of the `View`, it looks like this

```
+----------+
|Tex|      |
+----------+
|          |
|          |
+----------+
```

basically, that setting squishes the `TextInput` to much smaller width. How do I circumvent this?

as for code,
this one is the top image:

```
<TextInput />
```

This is the bottom:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <TextInput />
</View>
```

Comment: please show more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the input to fill the entire view use:

```
<TextInput style={{flex: 1}} />
```

if you want the text to be of a specific width use:

```
<TextInput style={{width: 100}} />
```

See this [example](https://rnplay.org/apps/qFM5Ag)